# I deleted my s3 bucket without disabling my s3 static web hosting. Would the web hosting be disabled automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I hosted a static website using s3 on aws. However later on I deleted my s3 bucket without disabling my static web hosting. Would the web hosting be disabled automatically

Comment: Yes, as bucket stop to exist. So what would it host?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes without any source the website will be gone.

If you have CloudFront or any other CDN then the website might still be there, served from CDN. Your DNS service might show an error page as well in case of CNAME doesn't exists.